# jquery start from hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script for my input button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('.menu-content').toggle('show');
    });
});
});//]]>
</script>
```

I need to start from hidden. How I can do that? Please, help me.

Comment: You would start from hidden using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend solved my problem like this:

```
<div class="dupa" style="display: none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('.dupa').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hide button by default with CSS rules:

```css
.menu-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the element to be hidden from the beginning, you can use some CSS like this:

```
<div style="display: none;">...</div>
```

This will hide the div, without any flickering. Once you call `.show()` using jQuery, the div gets shown.

Comment: yes but with this style I have big clear space :/ anyway, thanks for your time :)

Comment: `visibility: hidden` would result in a space. `display: none` in fact collapses the space that the div uses. Otherwise you have a different problem in your style.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
jQuery('#hideshow').click(function(event) {        
     jQuery('.menu-content').toggle();
});`
```

HTML:

```
<div style="display:none" class="menu-content">
hi
</div>
<input id="hideshow" type="button" value="show/hide">
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42rwkhL0/

you need to set the display attribute to "none" in the style of your menu-content item(s)

Answer (score 1):

as some before me have pointed - start with hidding the layer. then show it after the button is clicked. I have re-worked the code a bit:

```
   $('#hideshow').bind('touchstart click', function () {
       $('.menu-content').fadeIn(1000).css('display', 'inline');
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wktzv6hL/